# Using `mongoose transactions` when saving message in two collections in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, transactions

If the student sends a message to the teacher, the message is saved in the `teachers` and `students` collections. The same situation is when a teacher sends a message to the student, they are also save in the two collections `teachers` and `students`. How can I apply `mongoose transaction` in the following code so that the message is saved in two collections.I don' want a situation that the message will be saved in one collection and in the other collection will not be saved due to an error. I am asking for help and clues

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

//const app = express();

// Connect to our Database and handle an bad connections
module.exports.db = mongoose
    .createConnection(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    }
);




//controller
const db = require('./connection');

const session = db.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

module.exports.sendMessage = (req, res) => {
    
    let {sender, receiver, msg, role} = req.body;
    var hex = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;

    sender = (hex.test(sender))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sender) : sender;
    receiver = (hex.test(receiver))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(receiver) : receiver;
    console.log(sender, receiver, msg, 'send');

            if(role === 'tutor') {
                let teacherMessage =  new TeacherMessageSchema.TeacherMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    sender : sender
                })

                let studentMessage =  new TeacherMessageSchema.TeacherMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    receiver : receiver
                })
        
                db.db.collection('teachers').findOneAndUpdate( 
                    { _id : receiver },
                    { $push: { messages: teacherMessage } },
                    (err, updated) => {
                        console.log(updated, 'vvv');
        
                        updated.value.hashed_password = undefined;
                        updated.value.salt = undefined;
        
                        if(err) {
                            res.status(404).json(err);
                        }
        
                        if (updated) {
                            res.status(200).json(updated.value);

                            db.db.collection('students').findOneAndUpdate( 
                                { _id : sender },
                                { $push: { messages: studentMessage } },
                               
                            );
                        }
                    }, session(session)
                )
        
              
            }
        
        
            if(role === 'student') {
                let studentMessage =  new StudentMessageSchema.StudentMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    receiver : receiver
                })

                let teacherMessage =  new TeacherMessageSchema.TeacherMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    sender : sender
                })
        
               
        
                db.db.collection('students').findOneAndUpdate( 
                    { _id : sender },
                    { $push: { messages: studentMessage } },
                    (err, updated) => {
                        console.log(updated, 'sss');
            
                        updated.value.hashed_password = undefined;
                        updated.value.salt = undefined;
            
                        if(err) {
                            res.status(404).json(err);
                        }
            
                        if (updated) {
                            res.json(updated.value);
                            db.db.collection('teachers').findOneAndUpdate( 
                                { _id : receiver },
                                { $push: { messages: teacherMessage } },
                               
                            )
                        }
                    }, 
                ), session(session)
            }
}
```

**Logged variable db**

```
{
  db: NativeConnection {
    base: Mongoose {
      connections: [Array],
      models: [Object],
      modelSchemas: [Object],
      options: [Object],
      _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
      plugins: [Array]
    },
    collections: {},
    models: {},
    config: { autoIndex: true },
    replica: false,
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    relatedDbs: {},
    states: [Object: null prototype] {
      '0': 'disconnected',
      '1': 'connected',
      '2': 'connecting',
      '3': 'disconnecting',
      '99': 'uninitialized',
      disconnected: 0,
      connected: 1,
      connecting: 2,
      disconnecting: 3,
      uninitialized: 99
    },
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise]
    },
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [ReplSet],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    name: null,
    '$initialConnection': Promise { [Circular] },
    db: Db {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      serverConfig: [Getter],
      bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
      databaseName: [Getter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added in the code Anytime there is an error:

await session.abortTransaction();

Otherwise (happy path) commit the changes.

await session.commitTransaction();

Abort and commit are Promise base functions, so I have changed the functions where they were used as async.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

//const app = express();

// Connect to our Database and handle an bad connections
module.exports.db = mongoose
    .createConnection(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    }
);




//controller
const db = require('./connection');



module.exports.sendMessage = async (req, res) => {
    
    const session = await db.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    let {sender, receiver, msg, role} = req.body;
    var hex = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;

    sender = (hex.test(sender))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sender) : sender;
    receiver = (hex.test(receiver))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(receiver) : receiver;
    console.log(sender, receiver, msg, 'send');

            if(role === 'tutor') {
                let teacherMessage =  new TeacherMessageSchema.TeacherMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    sender : sender
                })

                let studentMessage =  new TeacherMessageSchema.TeacherMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    receiver : receiver
                })
        
                db.db.collection('teachers').findOneAndUpdate( 
                    { _id : receiver },
                    { $push: { messages: teacherMessage } },
                    async (err, updated) => {
                        console.log(updated, 'vvv');
        
                        updated.value.hashed_password = undefined;
                        updated.value.salt = undefined;
        
                        if(err) {
                            await session.abortTransaction();
                            res.status(404).json(err);
                            return
                        }
        
                        if (updated) {
                            res.status(200).json(updated.value);

                            db.db.collection('students').findOneAndUpdate( 
                                { _id : sender },
                                { $push: { messages: studentMessage } },
                               
                            );
                        }
                    }, session(session)
                )
        
              
            }
        
        
            if(role === 'student') {
                let studentMessage =  new StudentMessageSchema.StudentMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    receiver : receiver
                })

                let teacherMessage =  new TeacherMessageSchema.TeacherMessageSchema({
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    },
                    sender : sender
                })
        
               
        
                db.db.collection('students').findOneAndUpdate( 
                    { _id : sender },
                    { $push: { messages: studentMessage } },
                    async (err, updated) => {
                        console.log(updated, 'sss');
            
                        updated.value.hashed_password = undefined;
                        updated.value.salt = undefined;
            
                        if(err) {
                            await session.abortTransaction();
                            res.status(404).json(err);
                            return;
                        }
            
                        if (updated) {
                            res.json(updated.value);
                            db.db.collection('teachers').findOneAndUpdate( 
                                { _id : receiver },
                                { $push: { messages: teacherMessage } },
                               
                            )
                        }
                    }, 
                    session(session)
                )
            }

            await session.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: I have never used this in my code with Mongoose 5.11

Comment: I have error: `db.startSession is not a function`

Comment: I have error: `db.startSession is not a function. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Comment: Was the original code working with db.startSession() and moving inside the sendMessage function made this to fail? If this is the case.. it is weird. Can you logged the value of db before calling db.startSession?

Comment: I added logged `db`

Comment: do you have any clues?

Comment: Is the log you have posted inside of sendMessage? Or it is using your original code? And... what version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: yes, IT is log from inside of sendMessage. mongoose": "^5.1.4

Comment: Why do you have?

module.exports.db = mongoose
.....AND...
const db = require('./connection');

which one is the right db connection? the one you export or the one you require

Comment: I have 'db' w separate file so i import 'db' in controller  I have 'db' in file 'connection' . In file 'connection' I have:module.exports.db = mongoose
    .createConnection(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    }
);