# Unable to refer to method `db.start Session ()` in mongoose, mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

When I try to refer to `db.startSession ()` I have an error `db.startSession () is not a function`. In console.log I put `db` and I put logged variable below. Why can't I refer to `startSession()`?

**connection**

```
module.exports.db = mongoose
    .createConnection(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    }
);
```

**controller**

```
const db = require('./connection');

const session = db.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
```

**logged variable db**

```
{
  db: NativeConnection {
    base: Mongoose {
      connections: [Array],
      models: [Object],
      modelSchemas: [Object],
      options: [Object],
      _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
      plugins: [Array]
    },
    collections: {},
    models: {},
    config: { autoIndex: true },
    replica: false,
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    relatedDbs: {},
    states: [Object: null prototype] {
      '0': 'disconnected',
      '1': 'connected',
      '2': 'connecting',
      '3': 'disconnecting',
      '99': 'uninitialized',
      disconnected: 0,
      connected: 1,
      connecting: 2,
      disconnecting: 3,
      uninitialized: 99
    },
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise]
    },
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [ReplSet],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    name: null,
    '$initialConnection': Promise { [Circular] },
    db: Db {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      serverConfig: [Getter],
      bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
      databaseName: [Getter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this for using transaction in mongoose:

**Note**:for using transaction you need to replica mongodb, so you should Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set, and need to add  `retryWrites: false` as argument  in  `mongoose.createConnection()`

connect to mongoose :

```
      await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/namedb`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        retryWrites: false
      });
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
sess.startTransaction(); 
await teacher.save({ session: sess }); // a query
student.messeges.push(); // do somthing
await student.save({ session: sess }); //// a query
await sess.commitTransaction();
```

for using replica set in localhost you should stop mongod service and run this code

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\rs1 --replSet m101 --bind_ip localhost
```

`C:\data\rs1` data stored path

```
 rs.initiate()
```

Comment: This answer isn't correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765198/using-mongoose-transactions-when-saving-message-in-two-collections-in-mongodb/65766958?noredirect=1#comment116309223_65766958 ?

Comment: this code in my answer work for me, Does the way he said work correctly? I think its inccorect

Comment: I changed to `mongoose.startSession();` and I added `retryWrites: false` but I still have error `mongoose.startSession is not a function`

Comment: do you use last version mongoose?

Comment: version of mongodb is greater than 4? you should use 4.2

Comment: I use version `"mongoose": "^5.1.4",`

Comment: what is mongodb version?

Comment: "mongodb": "^2.2.33",

Comment: How can I find this path  C:\data\rs1?

Comment: your OS is windows or linux?

Comment: it is windows 10

Comment: create a folder in this path with same name c:\data\rs1

Comment: and I have to run this command `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\rs1 --replSet m101 --bind_ip localhost` in node.js command prompt?

Comment: first of all stop mognoDB service from services, after that run this command  in cmd

Comment: in this path C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin open cmd and run command

Comment: Is it possible that I didn't have installed mongodb on my computer and connected with database mongodb? I can't find folder Mongodb.

Comment: No It’s impossible

Comment: I killed mongodb services using command  `net stop MongoDB` and next I used `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\rs1 --replSet m101 --bind_ip localhost` but i still have error `db.startSession is not a function`

Comment: check the https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html , npm install run-rs based on link

Comment: when you run the command is every thing ok? did not see error?

Comment: define C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin in PATH of Environment variable if you install mongodb version 4.4

Comment: I defined it earlier

Comment: Don’t give up, it’s very easy, you can search about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227712/discussion-between-umbro-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).

Comment: Why you use twice student.save()??  await student.save({ session: sess }); // a query
student.messeges.push(); // do somthing
await student.save({ session: sess });